# Events used for login window in power builder 10.0

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-pfc

I have a login window for entering into my application, here I inserted a table named login1 and have two columns as `"username"` and `"password"` . I included the events for make "logging in" bye two cases 1) a command button 2) Enter key. So I Used to write these following code in button cliked event and a user event  that trigger the keydown of "Enter!" key.

```
if KeyDown(KeyEnter!) THEN   //In User Event case only
string ls_unm;
string ls_pass,ls_field;
ls_unm=dw_log.GetItemString(1,"user_name1");
ls_pass=dw_log.GetItemString(1,"password1");
select password1 into :ls_field  from login1 where login1.user_name1=:ls_unm;
if(ls_field=ls_pass) then  
commit; 
close (w_login);
open(w_main);
else
 rollback;
 messagebox( "","login faild");
 dw_log.Reset();
 dw_log.InsertRow(0);
 end if
    END if
```

but I got always "login faild" response even I checked through it by debug mode
how I make the proper login with this

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the "AcceptText" line?

```
if KeyDown(KeyEnter!) THEN   //In User Event case only
    string ls_unm;
    string ls_pass,ls_field;
    dw_log.AcceptText()
    ls_unm=dw_log.GetItemString(1,"user_name1");
    ls_pass=dw_log.GetItemString(1,"password1");
```

Answer (score 1):

I second Edurado about the `AcceptText()`.

Use `if dw_log.accepttext() <> 1 then return`, to handle any data validation failures.

Secondly, Command buttons have a `Default` property which will trigger the clicked event when user presses `enter` key. You need not use separate events for both. Just a humble opinion.

Comment: But when we use number of command buttons like as for save, Delete, Retrieve Which of these performs when the enter key pressed. I think we have to assign the enter pressed events for the finalizing operations such as save submit such like that

Comment: I guess i misunderstood your request. Weren't the question about a login window? Now, why would you use buttons for save/delete/retrieve functions there? Please enlighten me.